# How to fix an HTML video in a designed frame using bootstrap 4

Tags: html

I'm using bootstrap 4, and want to fix a video in image frame, Where do i need to set the encoding. and this is my code.

```
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
    style="background-image:url('img/video_Frame.png');
    background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;width:100%; height:31vw">

        <div class="box">
     <div id="video" class="embed-responsive shadow embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" style="width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
    style="background-image:url('https://diplomamess.ml/manager.jpg');padding:30px;background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;width:100%; height:100%;">

        <div class="box">
     <div id="video" class="embed-responsive shadow embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" style="width:100%; height:100%" style="box-shadow:0px 5px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, the code did not work properly as i want, i tried several times check different properties but did not work properly,